# time change after converting using NSDateFormatter

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to convert string to date. it works fine but the hours is different from the string. Here is my sample code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"2015-03-09 07:40:00 pm"];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

And, the output is `2015-03-09 08:16:43.794 testAlarm[1091:40476] 2015-03-09 10:40:00 +0000` notice the hour is 10 but in the string the hour is 07

Comment: `HH` should be for 24H format, and you have `pm`? The +3h is due I guess  to a timeZone issue.

Comment: i tried with hh small letter and the output is 2015-03-09 08:32:07.593 testAlarm[1116:44020] 2015-03-09 17:40:00 +0000

Comment: NSLog has no 'real' dateformatter attached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the time is read using your local timezone and the NSDate shown uses UTC time (as it always does when not using a specific date formatter

you explicity tell it to use the local timezone

```
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]]; //!
```

NSDate itself though is a timestamp without any notion of timezones

=> use a proper date formatter to print it. just logging it will always use no timezone => UTC

---

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"];
        [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
        [dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

        NSString *input = @"2015-03-09 07:40:00 pm";
        NSLog(@"%@", input); //local timezone
        NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:input];
        NSLog(@"%@", date); //utc!
        NSString *str = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
        NSLog(@"%@", str); //local timezone

    }
}
```

Comment: i updated my code its working fine now but i need to add AM/PM here is the new code     NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"2015-03-09 07:40:00"];
    NSLog(@"%@", date);

Comment: like larme said -- hh